# Basic algorithm to resize a 2D-matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, language-agnostic, linear-algebra

Let's say I have a black and white image of a "J", represented as a binary matrix, like this (white = 0, black = 1). If we let each cell in the matrix be a pixel, its size would be 6 x 10.

```
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I want to do is take this image and resize it by factor 10, that is, make it 10 times its current size, to 60 x 100. ( Of course there would be some interpolation need to happen, but it doesn't need to be overly sophisticated.)

I don't really get yet how this is done in practice. Is there a transformation matrix that can handle this? I [found an article that talk about using a resize matrix](https://datahacker.rs/003-how-to-resize-translate-flip-and-rotate-an-image-with-opencv/) (in my case 2 x 2 I guess). Do I need to apply that then? To every vector (every entry) in the matrix? And how can I then handle the interpolation to scale up the black pixels?

I was wondering if someone could provide either a simple example how this works using a scaling matrix or maybe provide me with some clues what to search for. My searches haven't been successful in order to find a simple/stripped down example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll use a smaller (5x4) version of your example:

```
. . T .
. . I .
. . I .
L . I .
. V . .
```

and scale it up by a factor of 3, multiplying by a 15x5 matrix on the left to scale vertically, and a 4x12 matrix on the right to scale horizontally:

```
1 0 0 0 0     . . T .     1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     . . . . . . T T T . . .
1 0 0 0 0  X  . . I .  X  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  =  . . . . . . T T T . . .
1 0 0 0 0     . . I .     0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0     . . . . . . T T T . . .
0 1 0 0 0     L . I .     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1     . . . . . . I I I . . .
0 1 0 0 0     . V . .                                 . . . . . . I I I . . .
0 1 0 0 0                                             . . . . . . I I I . . .
0 0 1 0 0                                             . . . . . . I I I . . .
0 0 1 0 0                                             . . . . . . I I I . . .
0 0 1 0 0                                             . . . . . . I I I . . .
0 0 0 1 0                                             L L L . . . I I I . . .
0 0 0 1 0                                             L L L . . . I I I . . .
0 0 0 1 0                                             L L L . . . I I I . . .
0 0 0 0 1                                             . . . V V V . . . . . .
0 0 0 0 1                                             . . . V V V . . . . . .
0 0 0 0 1                                             . . . V V V . . . . . .
```

I trust the pattern is clear.

Comment: Ah cool, that indeed makes sense. I haven't though about using 2 matrices. One and a half questions: 1. why did you pick the position of the 1's in the scaling matrices the way you picked? 2. Assuming the matrix could have fractions as values, any clue how to do interpolation?

Comment: 1. I saw that one scaling matrix wouldn't do, I needed two, one for vertical and one for horizontal. To scale the mxn matrix up to km rows I would need a kmxm left matrix. It must generate k copies of the first row of the original matrix, so the the first k rows of the left matrix must be `1 0 0 ...0`. After that it all followed easily. 2. There are many ways to do it. For instance, in my example, each pixel in the original maps to a 3x3 block of pixels; you could hold the center pixel fixed, and vary the eight others to make a smooth transition to the neighboring fixed centers.